# Read settings from app.config using ConfigurationManager

Tags: c#, settings, config

I have created a settings class where I added some parameters that are shown in the `app.config` below.

I want to access the `connectionStrings` and the `usersettings` inside my class but my attempts are not successful.

I've tried for example :

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings['Alerter.AlerterSettings.ConnectionString']
```

But it doesnt work.

Here is the `app.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Alerter.AlerterSettings.ConnectionString"     connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;sometext" />
</connectionStrings>
<userSettings>
    <Alerter.AlerterSettings>
        <setting name="TableName" serializeAs="String">
            <value>table5</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="EmailUser" serializeAs="String">
            <value>user</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="EmailPass" serializeAs="String">
            <value>pass</value>
        </setting>
    </Alerter.AlerterSettings>
</userSettings>
```

Comment: Do you have an _actual_ SQL connection string there?

Comment: @MUG4N - Why should they OP create a _custom_ configuration section?

Comment: @Oded: the connectionStrings section doesn't have to hold SQL connection strings.  There's no validation on the values in there.  People store SQL connection strings there by convention - the documentation for that section doesn't mention SQL or database anywhere except the example code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `'` - it is that *character* delimiter in C#, not a string delimiter:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Alerter.AlerterSettings.ConnectionString"]
```

You will also need to access the `ConnectionString` property of thee returned value:

```
string theConnectionString = 
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["whatever"].ConnectionString;
```

Note on naming:

`Alerter.AlerterSettings.ConnectionString` is rather verbose - it is not very readable in my opinion, and this is not needed for a configuration option - in particular as it is in the `connectionStrings` section. `AlerterSettings` to my eyes is much more appropriate.

Comment: but ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Alerter.AlerterSettings.ConnectionString"].ConnectionString causes a null reference exception

Comment: @user1709794 - Are you certain you have that value in the config file? Exactly like that? That error suggests that you may have put it in the wrong place (a different `.config` file?).

Comment: yes it turns out it access the app.config of another project, how can i fix that?

Comment: @user1709794 - Is this a class library? If so, that would be correct - it should access the configuration of the application that it using it. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674971/app-config-for-a-class-library

Comment: yes it is a class library, but the problem is that i am using it in two applications, so i was trying to put the settings inside the class library by creating a .settings class, the .settings class automatically created an app.config

Comment: @user1709794 - I see. That's where they are stored, but you shouldn't - create `.settings` in both applications that use it - that should work better.