# Read connection string information from assembly configuration

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am developing plug-in for a Windows Forms application. I am trying to use Entity Framework instead of a plain SqlConnection, but it does not work. The application throws the well-known exception:

> No connection string named 'testEntities' could be found in the application config file.

Of course I could add the connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="testEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://..." />
</connectionStrings>
```

But I do not have access to the configuration of the application that's running my plugin.

Is there way to use local config in Entity Framework?

Comment: `No connection string named 'testEntity'` and `<add name="testEntities"` is this intended?

Comment: Hi can you please show your DbContext class ? Also are you using EF code first approach ?

Comment: It's really unclear what you mean by "local config". You mean you have Entity Framework in a Class Library, and want the DbContext to use the connectionStrings section from the library's configuration file?

Comment: @YashveerSingh how is that relevant?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706122/entity-framework-6-connection-string-dll-app-config

Comment: Ok, I will add  DbContext class later. According to "local config" I just cant understand why SQL connection finds connection string but EF does not. So I suggested maybe EF uses another app.config . I comple my plugin to .dll and just drag and drop it to "Plugins" folder of another programm. I dont have access to parent programs source codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks everyone for responses and providing right direction.** I need only get default connection string from application config. So I modified DbContext file according to this answer
[EntityFramework 6 Code-based configuration of connection string for database-first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636508/entityframework-6-code-based-configuration-of-connection-string-for-database-fir)

Only difference

```
Properties.Settings.Default.TestConnectionString
```

Instead manually defined configuration.