# Use ConnectionStrings in .dll.config ( not current application .config)

Tags: asp.net, .net, winforms, dll, webforms

I am working on Windows Form Application in VisualStudio.
I am using .dll and .dll.config from other application (Asp.net Web Form).
When i run my window form application the error came up because of the connectionStrings.
It worked when i set that same connectionStrings from .dll.config into current application .config.
My question is: "how to make this application use .dll.config ?"

Thank you for your help.

Comment: DLLs should not have a config - only the app.  If you are dead set on using the library's config it's _possible_ (but not simple by any means), but the idiomatic way to configure an _application_ is through the app.config. That means copying the settings that are relevant to the windows app into the app.config.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674971) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190539) for more info.