# Error with App.config connectionstrign in class library

Tags: c#, sql, connection-string, class-library

I have an error with connection string in class library project.
In Appconfig I have this code:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-123\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDb;User ID=sa;Password=mypassword"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Connection string I call form a static function:

```
public static string ConnDb {
        get {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        }
    }
```

When I use this connection string in function

```
Sqlconnection conn = new Sqlconnection(Class1.ConnDb)
```

I have some error like

> {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

What can I do?

Comment: Where is the error occurring in the code? Have you stepped through the code to see what object is giving you the null reference?

Comment: Libraries don't have app.config, the running process does so put that connection string in the config of the running project.

Comment: I have error when i call class to get connectionstring

Comment: Possible duplicate of [app.config for a class library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674971/app-config-for-a-class-library)

Comment: App.config need to be in the project which uses this class library. Try that and let us know if you still face the issue

Answer (score 1):

you can user appSettings for alternative option.

Comment: Won't work if file is not part of calling application.

Comment: And connection strings are not usually per-user settings