# A C# Project library with app.config as dll reference to a azure function ,keys not accessible

Tags: c#, azure, function, dll, reference

A C# Project library with app.config file to access keys in project , When i add this project as dll reference to a azure function the keys used in dll are not able to access in metadata of dll and throwing error.

In function local.settings.json file i have added key with same name still issue

Comment: Can you please share the config file of class library and code how you are accessing them in function.

Comment: What is the framework of your app?

Comment: .Net Framework 4.6.1 of Dll project

Comment: The dll project has methods which uses connection string from app.config file , when i try to use that methods from a function , in metadata of dll methods it shows me null in config values

Comment: Are you running locally or in azure?

Comment: You want to access a config setting value from class library in Azure Function app?

Comment: Yes I am trying to run function local and calling a method of a dll but it's giving error while executing a query as connection string key is not loading from app.config file of dll

Comment: Check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5675099/19648279) answer once.

Comment: Iam able to retrieve the settings using `var test = Properties.Settings.Default.Setting1;`. Will post an answer in detail.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to retrieve the value of `app.config` settings in Azure Function app using the below code.

```cs
 var test = Properties.Settings.Default.Setting1;
```

[image]

***My `app.config`:***

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="ClassLibrary1.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ClassLibrary1.Properties.Settings.Setting1" connectionString="Test Value from app.config" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <userSettings>
        <ClassLibrary1.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Setting2" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Sample App setting</value>
            </setting>
        </ClassLibrary1.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Thanks @[Peter Morlion](https://blog.submain.com/app-config-basics-best-practices/) for the clear steps.

- In `Class library` => `Class1.cs`  file, add the below code

```cs
 public class Class1
 {
     public string GetAppSettings()
     {
         var setval = Properties.Settings.Default.Setting1;
         return setval;     
     }
 }
```

- Reference the class library dll in the `Azure Function` App.

[image]

***My `Function1.cs`:***

```cs
  [Function("Function1")]
  public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
  {
      Class1 appset = new Class1();
      var values = appset.GetAppSettings();

      _logger.LogInformation(values);
    -------
```

***Output:***
[image]

Comment: @harshita thanks for the detailed answer i have tried like above and its working fine , but in my scenario the function to which the project reference is added is an entry point to make methods call from function it is hitting the specific methods in project but the places where i am loading the keys from app.config are null like wise have multiple places with different keys

Comment: protected virtual string ConnectionString_Name { get; set; }

        public string ConnectionString => ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConnectionString_Name].ConnectionString; is getting null in existing code

Comment: I am not sure why the referenced project is not able to read its own app.config file. the variable string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnString"].ConnectionString; is getting null in referenced project

Comment: Check the properties of your app.config and change it as shown here.[Image](https://i.imgur.com/FqudORb.png)

Comment: Changed app.config properties as suggested and build the project , still same    https://imgur.com/a/KZndIv1

Comment: Instead of configuration manager try to retrieve using the properties in your function as I have mentioned above

Comment: I can't change accessing keys from configuration manager as it is referring to the metadata dll files of referenced project which are not editable.

Comment: Share your complete code repo